# Integrate 1+ google button in android with a button?

Tags: android, google-plus

I currently have a google sign in button with my game, but i would like to add a 1+ option without using the button provided by Google.

Does anyone know how to do this? is there a method or function of some sort that allows you to create your own 1+ button?